# Writing stacktrace into file using Logger produce empty file

Tags: java, logging, javafx

I need to log Exception stacktrace into log file but when an exception  occurs log file is empty. Stacktrace message is correct on terminal but log file is empty.

I tried classic logging api.

```
public class LoginController { 
public static Handler handler;

    {
        try {
            handler = new FileHandler("log"+File.separator+"error.log");
            Logger.getLogger(LoginController.class.getName()).addHandler(handler);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    public static void log(Level level, String name, Exception ex) {
        Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(name);
        logger.log(level, ex.fillInStackTrace().toString());
    }

//some code ...
catch (IOException e) {
                    log(Level.WARNING, LoginController.class.getName(), e);
                    handler.close();
                }
}
```

In error.log file is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="windows-1252" standalone="no"?>
<!DOCTYPE log SYSTEM "logger.dtd">
<log>
</log>
```

Stacktrace wasn't written! Where is a problem?

Comment: Your default log level is probably error but you are writing in warning. Try setting `Level.ERROR`

Comment: @ElliottFrisch Level.ERROR isn't exists! Just Level.ALL, Level.INFO, ...

Comment: Which `Logger` is this?

Comment: Doing the registering of this handler from an non-static initializer of a controller class seems bad design. What if you create an instance but only use static members? What if you create multiple instances of `LoginController`?

Comment: If you're using the `java.util.logging` (i.e. JUL) framework, then try `Level.SEVERE`.